# What are the material properties and features of the nano magnets?

Tags: the-matrix

In *Matrix: Resurrections* what are the nano magnets

> which comprise the real world form of Morpheus?

What are they made of, their material properties, features, and how do they work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *The Matrix Resurrections*, it is an invention called an **exomorphic-particle codex**. With the shared technology of synthients that made an alliance with humans, they invented this nanomagnet (magnetic nanoparticle) technology, which gave programs (like *Morpheus*) the ability to access the real world outside the Matrix.

When Neo asks "How does it work?", the answer was **paramagnetic oscillation**. They can also download the codex manual. There aren't any other details provided about the technology.

However, if we check what *paramagnetism* is and what *paramagnetic materials* are in the real world, it can give an idea:

> Paramagnetism is a form of magnetism whereby some materials are weakly attracted by an externally applied magnetic field, and form internal, induced magnetic fields in the direction of the applied magnetic field. 
> Paramagnetic materials include **aluminium, oxygen, titanium, and iron oxide (FeO)**. Therefore, a simple rule of thumb is used in chemistry to determine whether a particle (atom, ion, or molecule) is paramagnetic or diamagnetic: if all electrons in the particle are paired, then the substance made of this particle is diamagnetic; if it has unpaired electrons, then the substance is paramagnetic. 
> <sub>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism</sub>